# Online resource for reconnecting with other travelers?

Tags: online-resources, recommendations, romance

Last summer I spent some time in St. Petersburg, Russia. On the bus from Tallinn to St. Petersburg I met a nice girl. We also spent some time in St. Petersburg. Unfortunately, I've lost the email address she gave me there. So I've no possibility to contact her. Since I really would like to do that, I'm looking for an online platform that allows me to search for lost travelers. I remember her name, home town and more or less her itinerary. I could also describe her appearance very well ;)

Is there anything like that?

Comment: Facebook? (You should be able to search by name and hometown, assuming she's on Facebook and hasn't set her privacy settings too tight...)

Comment: Accessing passengers data is not allowed in most airlines (if not all). Specially after the flight is done only employees with proper authority can search the old flights..

Comment: @Gagravarr I already did the obvious research such as googeling or checking social networks

Comment: @HaLaBi I don't want to do that. Especially, because I don't know any of here flights. We took the bus together.

Comment: Stalkerrrrrrrrrrrrrrr!

Comment: you *could* add her details in here (or the chat), and some of those with, say, nefarious levels of google-fu might be able to come up with something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option (that may not suit you exactly, but will be useful for other searchers of a question like this) is [We Met On A Plane](http://wemetonaplane.com/).

[One media story](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/love-is-in-the-air-with-wemetonaplanecom-136986503.html) described it as the solution to the problem "Have you ever met that special someone on a plane but for whatever reason you didn't end up exchanging your contact details with each other and later regretted it? Without their name, how are you going to find them on Facebook?"

Answer (score 4):

In the US, you'd use Craigslist's missed connections. For example:

http://sfbay.craigslist.org/mis/

As @Gagravarr points out, your best international bet is probably Facebook, using her name and hometown as search paramaters. I've been able to find people I met while traveling on a few occasions like that.

There's also the sometimes surprisingly accurate (or creepy) http://kgbpeople.com. If your contact has a not too common name, you'd be amazed what sometimes comes out of there.